# Solve the differential equation of order $3$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation and find its solution $$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}=0$$

I haven't learnt yet how to solve differential equations of order $3$. Moreover, I don't think this can be solved as there is no variable which we can integrate. Even my textbook doesn't have the answer for this question. There's just this question and nothing else.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What order have you learned?

Comment: Integrate once by $x$ and you get second order linear ode. You can also substitute $y'''(x)=u''(x)$, etc.

Comment: Hint:  Integrate both sides of the equation repeatedly until you eliminate the derivatives.

Comment: @user619894 order $1$

Comment: so call $u(x)=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$, solve $\frac{du}{dx}=0$, repeat...

Comment: @user619894 got it! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an equation of the form $y^{(n)}=f(x)$, directly integrating three times gives the answer as all polynomial functions of degree $2$ or less: $Ax^2+Bx+C$ where $A,B,C$ are arbitrary constants.

Comment: So here $n$ can be any natural number$?$

Comment: @abcdefu What were you expecting? It just applies as long as you can apply it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by there being no variable you can integrate? You can integrate the zero function just as well as any other function by just noticing that if $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, then

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\alpha=0,$$

meaning that any constant function is an antiderivative of the zero function. Thus you can solve this problem by integrating three times, yielding

\begin{align*}
y&=\int\int\int 0~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int\int 2\alpha~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int (2\alpha x+\beta)~\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma
\end{align*}

for some $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ (not that I chose $2\alpha$ at the start to get rid of the $2$ at the end, it has not real effect on the solution).